# How to use members of a struct inside it?

Tags: matlab, struct

i'm trying to use a member defined in a struct to compute another member of the same struct. In particular I have:

```
DATI= struct(  'L_x',              1e7,...
               'L_y',              2*pi*1e6,...
               'H',                200,...
               'W',                0.3e-7,...
               'R',                0.6e-3,...
               'c_beta',           0,...            
               'c_gamma',          W*pi/(R*L_y),...
               'c_alpha',          [H*c_beta/R;0]);
```

In this way I cannot use members like 'W' or  'R', how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You must first define the structure as you're doing, then use its values. The fields of a structure can be accessed with a dot (`.`).

To define the `c_gamma` and `c_alpha` fields you can use:

```
DATI= struct(  'L_x',              1e7,...
               'L_y',              2*pi*1e6,...
               'H',                200,...
               'W',                0.3e-7,...
               'R',                0.6e-3,...
               'c_beta',           0);

DATI.c_gamma = DATI.W*pi/(DATI.R*DATI.L_y);
DATI.c_alpha = [DATI.H*DATI.c_beta/DATI.R;0];
```

or using strings for variable field names:

```
DATI= struct(  'L_x',              1e7,...
               'L_y',              2*pi*1e6,...
               'H',                200,...
               'W',                0.3e-7,...
               'R',                0.6e-3,...
               'c_beta',           0);

DATI.c_gamma = DATI.('W')*pi/(DATI.('R')*DATI.('L_y'));
DATI.c_alpha = [DATI.('H')*DATI.('c_beta')/DATI.('R');0];
```

You *cannot*, on the other hand, do this operation with a single command, like this:

```
DATI= struct(  'L_x',              1e7,...
               'L_y',              2*pi*1e6,...
               'H',                200,...
               'W',                0.3e-7,...
               'R',                0.6e-3,...
               'c_beta',           0,...            
               'c_gamma',          DATI.W*pi/(DATI.R*DATI.L_y),...
               'c_alpha',          [DATI.H*DATI.c_beta/DATI.R;0]);
```

because in the latter case the fields have not been created yet.

Comment: So I have to define first the struct without the fileds 'c_gamma' 'c_alpha' and then I can add them.

Comment: @betta_ Ooh, those are the fields... I edited the answer with two possibilities for you.